# graphical glitches in electron-based apps

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl, vmware-workstation, electron

**Context**:

Testing **electron-based applications** on a Ubuntu 22.04 (LTS) VM (upgraded from 21.10).  Specifically, I'm using VMWare workstation 12 on Windows 10, and the VM has the following OpenGL specs (some of which were updated just prior to the 22.04 upgrade).  Note the verbose errors regarding the missing configuration files - it's not clear whether these files are actually needed or not, and I can't figure out how to go about acquiring them if they are.

```
$ export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/qa/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: using driver vmwgfx for 4
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/qa/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: pci id for fd 4: 15ad:0405, driver vmwgfx
libGL: MESA-LOADER: dlopen(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so)
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/qa/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/qa/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/qa/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Using DRI3 for screen 0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.1.4 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.1.4 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 22.1.4 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

**Problem**:

Despite the fact that all graphics are stable in the latest public releases, **most text-based content is frequently garbled** in the latest internal builds of the next releases (which use a **newer version** of electron).  Often times, the text rendering corrects itself mid-session, but it often re-breaks as well.

The following errors are displayed when launching an app from the terminal. There are a few more, but they are reproducible with the previous versions too, so I omitted them:

```
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information  ## repeated 3 times
[4538:0722/102429.917451:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(292)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)  ## repeated ~20 times
```

**Current workarounds**:

- Disable hardware acceleration on the VM.  Given that the apps include windows with adjustable 3D content that requires OpenGL, this is undesirable.
- Downgrade the version of OpenGL used by the apps (see https://docs.mesa3d.org/drivers/svga3d.html).  Given that older versions of the apps did not require this, I suspect that this shouldn't be needed, and may cause problems in other areas.  So, I'm hoping that there's a different solution that allows the newer OpenGL to be used.  FWIW, the new errors mentioned above are still reproducible when this workaround is applied.